# Need help to parametrize the catenary by arc length

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, parametric, curves, plane-curves

The trace of the parametrized curve is

$$\alpha(t)=(t,\cosh t),\ t\in\mathbb R$$

is called catenary.

I want to show the curvature of the catenary is

$$k(t)=\frac{1}{\cosh^2t}$$

Before finding the curvature I need to parametrize it by arc length. Do Carmo in his [classical Differential Geometry book](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/docarmo.pdf) makes the following remark about it on page 22:

[image]
[image]

since the catenary is defined for every $t\in \mathbb R$, I'm having trouble to know the value of $t_0$, can it be anything?

Comment: yes; $0$ would be a convenient choice

Comment: Do you have go through to the arc length? If you use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) you can get the result you're looking for relatively straightforward

Comment: @NickPavlov can it be whatever I want?

Comment: "yes" was the answer to your actual question, "can it be anything?"

Comment: @NickPavlov what about the case $t<0$?

Comment: no matter what $t_0$ you choose, there will always be some $t < t_0$, but that's fine, for those the corresponding arc length will also be negative (they are in "the past")

Comment: @NickPavlov yes, they are negative, but what does it have to do with my actual question? I need a new parametrization which deals with every $t$. If I take $t_0=0$ the arc length parametrization is valid only for $t>0$

Comment: no, it will be valid for every $t$. The function $s(t)$ is from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, it takes care of all $t$'s

Comment: if you insist that "arc length" can only be non-negative (if I am correctly understanding the source of your discomfort), note that for the purposes of re-parametrization, arc length is also a "directed" quantity, that is from your chosen base point $\alpha(t_0)$ you can go forward ($s > 0$) as well as back ($s < 0$).

Comment: @NickPavlov I think I got it, we can take any $t_0\in I$. Thank you

Comment: In fact, you don’t need a paramerization to arc length, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202579/intuitive-definition-for-curvature/2202754#2202754

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the chain rule to do curvature/torsion computations for curves that are not arclength parametrized (and, of course, there are other formulas as well). This has been discussed in numerous MSE posts.

However, note that for your catenary, $s(t) = \displaystyle\int_0^t \sqrt{1+\sinh^2 u}du = \int_0^t \cosh u\,du = \sinh t$. And, using the quadratic formula (and the definition of $\sinh$), you can easily solve the equation $s=\sinh t$ for $t$ as a function of $s$ and reparametrize the curve. ... Again, whether you should want to is another matter.